# Peak time for autumn colours in Югыд ва/Yugyd Va (sub-polar Ural, Komi)

Tags: russia, autumn

I would like to enjoy autumn in Yugyd Va National Park.  In Northern Scandinavia, I have experienced that the peak autumn colours are approximately 25 August to 15 September in the Swedish and Finnish mountains, but 2–3 weeks later closer to the coast in Norway.  I think the larches in North America peak later yet.  When is the optimal time to enjoy autumn colours in Yugyd Va?

[image: Autumn in Yugyd Va]
Autumn in Yugyd Va National Park.  *Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82.jpg)*

Options may be:

- 16 August – 8 September
- 23 August – 15 September
- 30 August – 22 September
- 6 September – 29 September

I don't mind getting some snowfall, as long as it melts again within a couple of days and does not exceed 2 dm.

Comment: Why the downvote?